# PHP Script does not echo json encoded array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a php script which should echo a bunch of datasets in a json encoded string. Though the page is blank.

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("SERVER", "USER", "PASSWORD", "DATABASE");

if(!$sql = "SELECT news.title, news.content, login.username, news.id, news.date, news.timestamp, news.importance, news.version FROM news INNER JOIN login ON news.id = login.id ORDER BY timestamp DESC") {
    echo "FAIL";
}

mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$result = array();

while($row = $res->fetch_array())
{
    array_push($result,
    array('title'=>$row[0],
    'content'=>$row[1],
    'author'=>$row[2],
    'id'=>$row[3],
    'date'=>$row[4],
    'timestamp'=>$row[5],
    'importance'=>$row[6],
    'version'=>$row[7]
    )); 
}
$oldjson = json_encode(["result"=>$result]);

echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

What is the problem here? I tried some error detection with if(!..) but it did not help. I think the problem may be the array creation and/or echo, though I cannot figure out how to fix that.

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: The hell is this: `if(!$sql = "SELECT.....`???

Comment: Good question, does not make any sense. I just put if(!..) in front of every second query etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the result of json_encode, since you are encoding data that comes from the database you might have some stuff that requires escaping.

```
$json = json_encode(...);
if ($json === false) {
     echo "Error = " . json_last_error() . " " . json_last_error_msg();
     // You may want to var_dump the $result var here to figure out what the problem is
} else {
     echo $json; // Should be ok
}
```

Comment: 'Error = 5 Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded' is the result. I do not really get why because I only have text with utf8_unicode_ci  attributes in my table and also some integers.

Comment: I var_dumped it and there is nothing which should not be there. I do not know what could cause that error.

Comment: Try 
`mysqli_set_charset("utf8",$con)` 
right after you create the connection